# I wanna create a dynamic editable tables on DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I set up a Wizard and I wanna add tables in every step, finally I will have a lot of dynamic tables. The goal is to facilitate the tasks and accelerate the development.

Does django have a module that allows:

1. Dynamically add tables
2. user can edit the tables and modifying the database automatically.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: you mean the table is database table, or html table?

Comment: Html table @NamjuYoon

Answer (score 1):

You can use some javascript plugins for do that.

I prefer handsontable - you can use community edition for light function.

You can save database using ajax.

See [here](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable) for more detail.

Comment: And if I dont want to use javascript ? @seuling

Comment: Then it's really hard to make the table dynamically. There're some options for using websocket like `channels`, but it's basically using javascript. I guess it's impossible to make without javascript.